# Pandas dtype=datetime64[ns] and date error

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create the 3 and 6 months data frame. following error occured. My data contains entries from jan to sept. I have imported relevant files. Please help me.

**Code I tried:**

```
tx_data = pd.read_excel('final2.xlsx')

tx_data['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(tx_data['InvoiceDate'])


#create 3m and 6m dataframes

tx_3m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= date(2021,1,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < date(2021,3,1))].reset_index(drop=True)

tx_6m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= date(2021,3,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < date(2021,9,1))].reset_index(drop=True)

#create tx_user for assigning clustering

tx_user = pd.DataFrame(tx_3m['CustomerID'].unique())

tx_user.columns = ['CustomerID']
```

**Error StackTrace:**

```
InvalidComparison                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in wrapper(self, other)
    115         try:
--> 116             other = _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    117         except InvalidComparison:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
     95         elif not is_list_like(other):
---> 96             raise InvalidComparison(other)
     97 

InvalidComparison: 2021-01-01

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f685d23cc10a> in <module>
      6 #create 3m and 6m dataframes
      7 
----> 8 tx_3m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= date(2021,1,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < date(2021,3,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
      9 tx_6m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= date(2021,3,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < date(2021,9,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
     10 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    368         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True)
    369 
--> 370         res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    371 
    372         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    228     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):
    229         # Call the method on lvalues
--> 230         res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
    231 
    232     elif is_scalar(rvalues) and isna(rvalues):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in wrapper(self, other)
    116             other = _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    117         except InvalidComparison:
--> 118             return invalid_comparison(self, other, op)
    119 
    120         dtype = getattr(other, "dtype", None)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\invalid.py in invalid_comparison(left, right, op)
     32     else:
     33         typ = type(right).__name__
---> 34         raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     35     return res_values
     36 

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

Comment: Add this import in your code -----> from datetime import datetime and then Use datetime instead of date in your conditions.

Comment: from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date. I have already imported this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both sides as `datetime.date` format, convert the column like this in your code, while comparing:

```
tx_data.InvoiceDate.dt.date >= date(2021,1,1)
```

The issue now in your code is, `tx_data.InvoiceDate` is `datetime64[ns]` and `date(2021,1,1)` is `datetime.date` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your calls to `date` with [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), as follows:

```
tx_3m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= pd.Timestamp(2021,1,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < pd.Timestamp(2021,3,1))].reset_index(drop=True)

tx_6m = tx_data[(tx_data.InvoiceDate >= pd.Timestamp(2021,3,1)) & (tx_data.InvoiceDate < pd.Timestamp(2021,9,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

[`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) produces type of `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` which can be compared with `Pandas dtype=datetime64[ns]` objects.